# This type of extension can't update automatically. Update will appear on the update tab

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I need to update extension Asp.net frameworks and web tools for creating project with Angular2,

[image]

Comment: Can i fix this issue with repairing visual studio?

Comment: http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/04/05/updating-extensions-automatically-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: okay,,thnak you )))